# DAX Measure: Slicer using 2 columns

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

I have two columns with numbers from 1 to 10, for example:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |

I have to create a slicer that will filer other columns (Column C, Column D....) based on the numbers in Column A and B like this:

If there is 1 in a row from Column A or in Column B, show a row from Column C and Column D.

So the slicer should filter the rest of the columns based on the fact if those columns have a number that is contained in Column A OR in Column B.

I searched for the solutions, but people usually recommend creating a table with those two columns, but that is over the top for me. I tried with switch function, but it is not working properly aka not good for the slicer and slicer is the only option for filtering for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, the slicer will need to use a column from a different table. Let's help you do so.

In `Report View`, select `New Table` in the `Modeling` tab in the ribbon, and paste in one of these expressions:

```
// if you want all the unique values of column A and B in the slicer:
Slicer A B = 
  SELECTCOLUMNS(
    DISTINCT( UNION( DISTINCT(YourTable[Column A]), DISTINCT(YourTable[Column B]) ) ),
    "Slicer", [Column A]
  )

// Or if you want 1 to 10, then use this:
Slicer A B = 
  SELECTCOLUMNS(
    GENERATESERIES(1, 10, 1),
    "Slicer", [Value]
  )
```

Next, create a new Measure with:

```
Count A B = 
  CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(YourTable), 
    YourTable[Column A] IN VALUES('Slicer A B'[Slicer]) || 
    YourTable[Column B] IN VALUES('Slicer A B'[Slicer])
  )
```

Now add a slicer from `'Slicer A B'[Slicer]` column, and in the Table visual, add a Visual Filter with `Count A B` `is not blank`.

And that should be it.

Comment: I know how to create a New table :), I was just hoping this can be done without creating the new one, let's say more optimally, by using only a measure. I usually try not to create new table nor columns. I was taught it is kind of a bad practice because it uses space in vain. But it looks like I will need to create one for this case. Thank you none the less, you are the best. :)

Comment: Having a slicer "slice" the same table it is in is perfectly fine if you want to filter the rows unconditionally. In this case, it needs to be separate and one could consider the new table as an additional Dimension to your "Fact" table. Please Accept the answer above when ready, for the benefit of all.